# Any ideas as to why this query doesn't return any results?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) AS "NUMSECTIONS"
FROM students s
INNER JOIN registration r
ON s.studentid = r.studentid
INNER JOIN sections e
ON r.sectionid = e.sectionid
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, registrationdate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
AND registrationdate >= To_Date('Jun 15 2020 12:00 AM', 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI AM')
ORDER BY numsections DESC, lastname, firstname;
```

I am just trying to show the students registered on or after June 15th 2020 at midnight that are taking more than 10 sections. Query runs but returns columns without any rows

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE registrationdate >= To_Date('Jun 15 2020 12:00 AM', 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI AM')
GROUP BY firstname, lastname  --, registrationdate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
--AND registrationdate >= To_Date('Jun 15 2020 12:00 AM', 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI AM')
ORDER BY numsections DESC, lastname, firstname;
```

- remove `registrationdate` from the `group by` clause; it causes problems because - with it - you're grouping result by something you don't need (nor want)
- move condition into `WHERE` clause (from `HAVING`)

Once you do that (with my simple sample data):

```
SQL> with
  2  students (studentid, firstname, lastname) as
  3    (select 1, 'Little', 'Foot'  from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Big'   , 'Foot'  from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Scott' , 'Tiger' from dual),
  6  registration (studentid, registrationdate, sectionid) as
  7    (select 1, date '2020-08-23', 100 from dual union all -- student 1 registered to 3 sections
  8     select 1, date '2020-08-24', 200 from dual union all
  9     select 1, date '2020-08-15', 300 from dual union all
 10     select 2, date '2020-11-15', 100 from dual union all  -- student 2 registered to 2 sections
 11     select 2, date '2020-12-18', 300 from dual union all
 12     select 3, date '2020-12-11', 200 from dual),          -- student 3 registered to 1 section
 13  sections (sectionid) as
 14    (select 100 from dual union all
 15     select 200 from dual union all
 16     select 300 from dual)
 17  --
```

Query:

```
 18  SELECT firstname, lastname,
 19    COUNT(*) AS "NUMSECTIONS"
 20  FROM students s
 21  INNER JOIN registration r
 22  ON s.studentid = r.studentid
 23  INNER JOIN sections e
 24  ON r.sectionid = e.sectionid
 25  WHERE registrationdate >= To_Date('Jun 15 2020 12:00 AM', 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI AM')
 26  GROUP BY firstname, lastname  --, registrationdate
 27  HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
 28  ORDER BY numsections DESC, lastname, firstname;

FIRSTN LASTN NUMSECTIONS
------ ----- -----------
Little Foot            3
Big    Foot            2
Scott  Tiger           1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried removing that but now it returns with: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 5`

Comment: Sorry; condition should be moved into WHERE clause. Have a look at edited answer, please; now it contains some sample data and query itself.

Comment: Sort of works now, could my count function not count the sections table correctly? Set the HAVING COUNT to > 0 and it shows results but they're all < 5 and the wanted results are : `Majorie  Goodmanson  22
Corrina  Hinman  20
Verena  Ferrari 19` etc.

Comment: I don't have *real* data so I can't tell for sure but - with "improved" sample data (see edited answer) - COUNT function returns correct result. Once again - with **my** data.

Comment: Ok, I will keep trying to tweak it to see what I'm missing, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter on the date before aggregating. Additionally, if you have two students with the same name then your query will aggregate them together; you should `GROUP BY` the unique identifier for each student.

```sql
SELECT MAX(s.firstname) AS firstname,
       MAX(s.lastname) AS lastname,
       COUNT(*) AS numsections
FROM   students s
       INNER JOIN registration r
       ON s.studentid = r.studentid
       INNER JOIN sections e
       ON r.sectionid = e.sectionid
WHERE  r.registrationdate >= DATE '2020-06-15'
GROUP BY
       s.studentid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
ORDER BY
       numsections DESC,
       lastname,
       firstname;
```